# how to increase session timeout in webdriver.io

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, mocha.js, webdriver-io

I have a long-running test (between 2 and 3 hours). At the end of the mocha test, it tries to deleteSession, but fails due to an expired session. How to increase session timeout or are there any other methods to solve the ERROR [image]
Console log:
[0-0] 2021-02-16T12:33:01.333Z INFO webdriver: [DELETE] http://localhost:4444/wd/hub/session/29a818df4e4c33e10d35714c5553bc6d
[0-0] 2021-02-16T12:33:01.338Z DEBUG webdriver: request failed due to status 6
[0-0] 2021-02-16T12:33:01.340Z ERROR webdriver: Request failed with status 404 due to invalid session id: No active session with ID 29a818df4e4c33e10d35714c5553bc6d
[0-0] 2021-02-16T12:33:01.343Z ERROR @wdio/local-runner: Failed launching test session: invalid session id: No active session with ID 29a818df4e4c33e10d35714c5553bc6d

I tried to increase script timeout in wdio.conf, but it did not help[image]